# Factored form of a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is there a way to formulate a factored form formula (not the roots) for $ax^2+bx+c$ in terms of $a, b,$ and $c \,?$

Starting from the AC method of factoring, we derive these two equations:

$$\frac{ac}m=n \quad,\quad  m+n=b.$$

I solved the systems by substituting $\frac{ac}{m}$ into $n.$

$$m^2 - bm + ac = 0.$$

After completing the square, I found $m, n$ , which equals:

$$ \frac{b±\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2$$

So now $ax^2+bx+c$ is equal to
$$ax^2 + \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2}x + \frac{b-\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2x + c$$

This is where I got stuck. My thinking led me to believe that I needed to derive a formula for the greatest common integer to factor out any divisor that is divisible by $a,b,c.$ Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you trying to factor $ax^2+bx+c$ ??

Comment: What do you mean by "the greatest commom complex number divisor" ??

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to factor ax^2 + bx + c. I mean the greatest common divisor.

Comment: But the GCD of what ??

Comment: The greatest common divisor of a, n, m, and c.

Comment: *" What's surprising is it is so similar to the quadratic equation. "* How do you think quadratic formula was derived in the first place ?

Comment: $ax^2 + bx + c$ is not equal to 
$ax^2 + \left(b +\frac{\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2\right)x + \left(b -\frac{\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}2\right)x + c$ which equals $ax^2 + 2bx + c$

Comment: You wrote it wrong. I edited your slight mistake.

Comment: The quadratic formula was derived by dividing all the terms by a and then completing the square. That's not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - I am responding to your post above. I am confused as to how m= [b +(b^2 -4ac)^1/2]/2 (my original post) is not essentially a fraction since you have brackets around b +(b^2 -4ac)^1/2. Just trying to understand. May you please explain Paul?

Comment: My apologies. Those text expressions can be particularly hard to keep track of what is in and out of parentheses (which is why mathjax is such a blessing). You did indeed have it correct.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair No apology needed, I am just glad your concerned.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment on Yves Daoust's now-deleted post (which I would still upvote if it were allowed), you said you want a formula to convert
$$54x^2 -171x + 135$$ to $$9(2x-3)(3x-5)$$
instead of to $$a(x-r_1)(x - r_2)$$
which for this quadratic is actually
$$54\left(x - \frac 32\right)\left(x - \frac 53\right)$$

Note how I found that: I took your factorization, pulled a $2$ out of the first factor, a $3$ out of the second factor, and combined them with the $9$ in front.

It goes the other way as well. If I had solved the problem to get 
$$54\left(x - \frac 32\right)\left(x - \frac 53\right)$$
and decided I didn't like those unsightly fractions, I can just multiply the first factor by $2$, the second factor by $3$ and divide them both out of the constant in front:
$$54\left(x - \frac 32\right)\left(x - \frac 53\right) = \frac{54}{2\cdot3}(2x-3)(3x-5) = 9(2x-3)(3x-5)$$
This is the formula you are after as far as I can see. Solve the quadratic as normal, then multiply through to get rid of the fractions. There is no factoring without finding the roots. To factor a polynomial into degree-$1$ factors *is to find the roots*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach based on attempting to find a perfect square "hidden" in the expression
$$ ax^2+bx+c $$

In order to have a perfect square in the expression, we would like the first term to be a perfect square. So we begin by multiplying and dividing the expression by $4a$. [There is a reason that $4$ works best and I will give a hint: try multiplying by $ak^2$ and try to see why $k$ should be equal to $2$.]

$$ \frac{1}{4a}\cdot(4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac) $$

Now notice that the square of $2ax+b$ equals $4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2$. So we can re-write the expression as

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{4a}\cdot(4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2 -b^2+4ac)&=&\frac{1}{4a}\cdot[(2ax+b)^2-(b^2-4ac)]
\end{eqnarray}

Now the second expression can be written as the difference of two squares:

$$ \frac{1}{4a}\cdot{\large[}(2ax+b)^2-(\sqrt{b^2-4ac})^2{\large]}$$

This can be factored into the product of a sum and difference to give

$$ \frac{1}{4a}\cdot{\large[}(2ax+b)-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}{\large]}\cdot{\large[}(2ax+b)+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}{\large]} $$

This is one way to factor $ax^2+bx+c$. If you set it equal to $0$ and solve for $x$ you will quickly arrive at the quadratic formula.